# Default keyword like (Where) creates issue, when it used in external parameter of method with swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Actually, I am using one of the **third party library** and it is integrated in to my swift project.

In library some methods signature have used **Where** keyword as **external parameter** and Seems that create trouble to call method from swift code.

```
var result = modelHandler.search(CustomerModel.self, where:[:], orderBy: "", offset: 0, count: 10)
```

**Method signature in objective c:**

```
-(NSMutableArray *)search:(Class)modelClass where:(id)where orderBy:(NSString *)orderBy offset:(NSInteger)offset count:(NSInteger)count
```

Error says something like : **Expected separator ', '**

Comment: Can you show us the signature of search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few tries in Playground, I was able to find that it is not possible to use "where" as a parameter name in a method as it is a reserved word in Swift.

The following method declarations give me the same issue message:

> Expected ',' separator

```
func sayHello(integer: Int, #where: [String : Int]) {
    println("Hello")
}

func sayHello(integer: Int, where: [String : Int]) {
    println("Hello")
}
```

**However**, the [Swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) states:

> To use a reserved word as an identifier, put a backtick before and
>   after it.

Therefore, the following code will compile:

```
// Note the use of backticks (`)
func sayHello(integer: Int, `where`: [String : Int]) {
    println("Hello")
}
```

Comment: I just found solution from apple's document. Thanks for your effort. Your answer covers the solution

Comment: Excerpt from Apple's document: _If you need to give a constant or variable the same name as a reserved Swift keyword, surround the keyword with back ticks (`) when using it as a name. However, avoid using keywords as names unless you have absolutely no choice._